# SQL Geography string parsing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, geospatial, geography

Why does this work

```
select geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-77.010996 38.890358)',4326)
```

but this doesn't

```
declare @Latitude decimal(9,6) = 38.890358  
declare @Longitude decimal(9,6) = -77.010996

select geography::STGeomFromText('''POINT(' + 
cast(@Longitude as nvarchar(15)) + ' ' + 
cast(@Latitude as nvarchar(15)) +')''',4326)
```

What am I missing, they seem to be effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the extra quotes at the begining and end

```
declare @Latitude decimal(9,6) = 38.890358  
declare @Longitude decimal(9,6) = -77.010996

select geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + 
cast(@Longitude as nvarchar(15)) + ' ' + 
cast(@Latitude as nvarchar(15)) +')',4326)
```

Comment: wow, do I feel like a fool. Just one of those brain fart moments, thanks.